# how to pass parameters to returnURL MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, returnurl

Problem:
Customer click 'Book' link and is redirected to the LogIn page.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Book", "BookVisit", new { time = Model.availableTimesList[i].TimeOfDay, date = Model.dateOfAppointment, providerID = Model.providerID })
```

After loging in I would like him to be redirected to the page where he originally wanted to get. I use this code in custom Authorize Attribute:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
     filterContext.Result = new System.Web.Mvc.RedirectResult("/UserAccount/LogIn/?ReturnUrl=" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath+ "?" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString);
}
```

but to this method:

```
[AuthorizeUser(AccessLevel = "User,Admin")]
public ActionResult BookVisit(DateTime time, DateTime date,int providerID)
```

get only first parameter. Why and how to pass all of them?

Comment: What does that redirect URL look like? Using the browser's network monitor what does that redirect request look like?

Comment: I already spot an extra `?`. Check the redirect URL you are constructing.